# Is there a way to view the C code underlying Java?

Tags: java, c, bytecode

I know that you can view the "source code" for Java on places like grepcode, but I'm looking for some way to view the C code which Java is built on top of. I feel that this question must have been asked many times, but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer.

This is not for any explicit purpose - I just want to understand how a programming language is "built" a little bit better.

Also, if someone could show how to view the bytecode generated, that would probably help too.

Comment: I don't know about Java 6 or Java 7, but Java 8 is open source

Comment: I've found in my JDK 1.7.0_21 folder on my Windows installation a src.zip file. Inside it, there is a *launcher* folder with .c and .h files that might solve your curiosity (specially java.c and main.c).

Comment: Those files are just the trivial wrapper around the JVM library. The source for the JVM can be obtained elsewhere.

Comment: @Luiggi - The only .c file in there I could find was rather small. It seems impossible that it could be holding the entire Java language within it, so I think what I'm looking for is slightly different. Perhaps what I'm looking for is the compiler? Or is that the same as the JVM? I'm new to this, so please forgive my ignorance and bungling of terms.

Comment: I answered your question below, and told you why Luigi's comment is wrong. Is this mike on?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't respond to yours yet because I'm trying to figure out if I'm misunderstanding how it all works. But I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. In the file I downloaded, nearly all the files seem to be only a few lines long. Though it's in C, it doesn't seem to be specifying the syntax of Java. But perhaps I'm just looking in the wrong place? Any suggestions? (I didn't downvote you, just so you know.)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill thanks for the OpenJDK project link, sadly I can't download the source code for having a slow internet connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle's official JDK 7 is based on the code from [the OpenJDK project](http://openjdk.java.net/), which you can download from that link. There's also a JDK 8 branch available from the same site.

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is a sort of imaginary computer that executes `*.class` files. Most of the time, the JVM is *emulated* by a program written in some other language (like C++) which runs on a real computer. When you run a Java program on your Windows machine, for example, the program `java.exe` which is written largely in C++, pretends to be a JVM, and executes your `*.class` files. Java code like

```
++i;
```

gets translated by the Java compiler (which is written in Java!) into a JVM opcode like

```
iinc 0 1
```

The JVM contains code (written in C++, or assembly) to handle that instruction -- and all the hundreds of additional instructions -- as if it were an opcode in a real machine language. In truth, it's actually even more complicated: all modern JVMs translate those JVM opcodes into platform-specific machine code while they're running, But the code that does that translation is of course written in some native (non-Java) language like C++ or assembly.

There are lots of articles on the Interwebs that explain this stuff well: [here's a nice one.](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvmP.html)

Comment: Is Java even written in C? Or does it just go Java -> bytecode -> processor level... I'm obviously way out of my depth here, but it's surprisingly hard to find any sources online which give the "big picture" of what's going on. I know this probably seems like I'm off-topic, but if Java isn't even written in C (or C++), perhaps my question is moot.

Comment: I added some material and a good pointer as to where you could learn more.

Comment: @Chris: Hotspot, the standard JVM, is written in C/C++ (mostly C++). But you can write a VM in any language you like, even Java.